# How is Apache bypassing file and directory permissions?

Tags: apache, logging

I have my website logs stored in a particular location on my webserver. This directory has the following permissions set.

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root      4096 Oct 12  2013 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root      4096 Feb  4  2015 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 482757851 Jul 13 02:28 access.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   3996253 Jun 23 18:19 error.log
```

As you can see www-data does not have writeable access to this directory. How then is Apache able to create and update the log files? Does it run as root to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I don't know the mechanism exactly, but its along the lines of the parent process runs as root and when it forks worker processes it drops those priviliges and runs them as www-data.

It must run as root in order to bind to port 80, which is a restricted port. The same process that handles the binding of this port also handles the logging, hence it has access to the files and directory you have shown.

Comment: The parent process doesn't handle the logging, anything logged comes from the child worker processes, but the log file is opened as ``root`` user in parent before the child worker processes are forked, so it inherits the open file descriptor.